# Bluimp Backload folder reference issue with virtual directories

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, virtual-directory, blueimp, backload

I am working on a solution which has two projects in it. One is a virtual app which works in another. The first application is the panel and the second is the website. First application can be accessed with "localhost:10001/panel" and the second with "localhost:10001". You see, I created a virtual path for the first app to work under the second one in Visual Studio and they work great that way.

The problem I am having now is about the file uplaod system, "[Blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)" plugin and as backend using "[Backload](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload)". I must say that these work great on a standalone project. That's why I decided to continue the project using these.

But when it comes to a setup which I explained below, I cannot access the files I upload. I installed fileupload system in the panel project, which is accessed as "localhost:10001/panel" so when I leave the default web.config configuration for backload (default is "~/files"), all files are uploaded to the "localhost:10001/panel/files" path. And after the upload when I refresh the page, all uploaded file links are referencing "localhost:10001/files/" without the "panel" folder.

In BackLoad web.config notes how to change and use root upload folders are explained like that

*filesRoot:        // Root upload folder. If the value starts with '~/' (e.g. ~/files) the path is relative to the web root, otherwise set an absolute local path (e.g. d:/files) [Default: "~/Files"].*

I understand that having "~/" at the beggining of a folder reference shows the project's root. But I can't figure out how to reference the upload folder, instead of the default "~/files", to upload and access all files from the second project's root. When I need to reference folder between these two projects I simple use "../", or "/" to access the second project's (site) root. But doing that in "filesRoot" attribute of BackLoad config settings, all file references are starting "///file....." and shows a local path in the computer.

I simply want to upload and access the files from the "localhost:10001/files" location when I upload files from the panel. Now, I cannot even use the "localhost:10001/panel/files" path because files are uploaded to "panel/files" folder, but are accessed from "files" folder with default settings.

BTW: I am using [BackLoad's WebForms Example](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/tree/master/Examples/_HowTos/ASPNETWebForms) on this project, and this is a Web Forms project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Files folder as a temp folder. At the time of submit, I move the file which is uploaded in Files folder, to the folder of my need. And the problem is solved.

Thanks anyway...